# How to pass attributes from a React component to a web-component?

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I have the following web-component:

```
(function() {
    var helloProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    helloProto.createdCallback = function() {
        var val = this.getAttribute('data-text') || 'stranger';
        val = val.toUpperCase();    
        this.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + val + '.';
    };

    document.registerElement('hello-el', {
        prototype: helloProto
    });
})();
```

Which is called like this from the render function of a React component:

```
<hello-el data-text="roger"></hello-el>
```

The problem is that this.getAttribute('data-text') returns undefined ? Why ?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do it... But looks like you run this function before `<hello-el />` is rendered. You should run it in `componentDidMount`, for example. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpNRPY

Comment: It even works if I move the code outside the componentDidMoun function. But this codeine is using an older React version than my failing example. Maybe it doesn't working with newer  React versions ?

Comment: it works if the getAttribute call is moved to the attributeChangedCallback